# Backbone Event for VIEW doesn't trigger if we click on a link which has the HREF which is already there in the URL

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I have a view where i have 3 links(routers which have methods triggering a View bound event).
Normally based on the link i click i reduce from the main collection a subset and render it in another VIEW.

But suppose i have clicked on a link say '....#/remaining' and then i click again on the same link, the event bound is not triggered.

But when i click on any other link and click back on the desired link, everything works!

Is this a Backbone feature/defect, if so what are the alternatives to work around this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please show your code here so I can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're doing the reduce in the Router. When you're already on #remaining, your route handler won't execute because there's no route change at all.

Instead of that, you could use a View UI event on the link to manipulate the collection, so it will always be called no matter if you're already on that route or not.

You could also use events as a communication method between your app's components: your data, your views, and so on.

Hope it helps, I didn't put any code because you didn't either. :)